# How to combine row + columm in a pie box?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, pie-menu

I assumed with defining each layout type I could stack a line of row above a set of columns but it seems not to work. You can see that the column is at position 8 and not below the rows at position 2.

[image]

```
    box = pie.split().box().column()
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth")
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")
    box = pie.box()
    col = box.column()
    col.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth", text="Mesh Smooth")
    col.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat", text="Mesh Flat")
    col.separator()
    col.operator("mesh.normals_make_consistent", text="Normals Outside").inside=False
    col.operator("mesh.flip_normals", text="Flip Normals")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face", text="Show Face Normal")
    col.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size", text="Size")
    col.prop(view, "use_occlude_geometry", text="Hide Back Geometry")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.split()` is meaningless for pie menus, it has no effect. When you assign another item to the pie it will be at another position (so top).

To fix it you need to group everything inside a column and create the gap with `.separator()`:

```
    # ...
    group = pie.column()

    box = group.box()
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth")
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")

    group.separator()

    box = group.box()
    box.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth", text="Mesh Smooth")
    box.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat", text="Mesh Flat")
    box.separator()
    box.operator("mesh.normals_make_consistent", text="Normals Outside").inside=False
    # ...
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see - I guess that I then copied already bad code and made it worse hahaha. Thank you very much!